# Facebook App redirect to domain

Tags: facebook, codeigniter, facebook-apps, facebook-authentication

I am creating Facebook application using PHP, in authentication process, facebook redirect to my domain,

This is simple code to get authentication::

```
 $params = array(
 'scope' => 'email,user_about_me, user_birthday, user_location');
  $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" . "top.location.href = '" . $url. "';</script>";
```

if i write a 'redirect_url' = 'https://apps.facebook.com/appname'
then app is go in infinite loop.

i am confused to find out the solution. I am develop this application in PHP codeIgniter Framwork.please help me, thanks advance.

Comment: Have u tried in different browsers? i too had this issue once .. after switching browser to Mozilla that problem was solved.. i assume u trying in localhost.... with Chrome browser.

Comment: Rajesh : No dud, It's not browser problem and i am not try it with localhost, but problem is that when i load application then it redirect to my server.

Comment: After you get redirect, do you check if you have the user's id or not by `getUser()` to stop any further redirection ?

Comment: After redirecting server, application is run normally on server with grab all user datas. only problem of redirect..:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try this?

```
$params = array(
 'scope' => 'email,user_about_me, user_birthday, user_location',
 'redirect_uri' => 'http://apps.facebook.com/yourappsnamespace'
);
  $url = $this->facebook->getLoginUrl($params);
 echo "<script type='text/javascript'>" . "top.location.href = '" . $url. "';</script>";
```